# How to get time difference of a datetime value and a time value in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time, strtotime

I have one DATETIME value 'D1' and one TIME value 'T1'. I need to find difference of D1 and T1 after comparing these two values.
D1:2020-12-07 18:21:47 and T1:19:30:00
My code to find time difference:

if(strtotime(T1) > strtotime(D1)){
$diff = date("H:i:s",(strtotime(T1) - strtotime(D1)));
}`

I am getting incorrect result.

Comment: What result are you getting  ?
What is your expected result out of above example?

Comment: I am expecting 01:08:13 but m getting 06:38:13

Answer (score 0):

> use this method to add date to your t1 value

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2020-12-07 18:21:47'));
```

> and then use this method to get difference

```
 $starttimestamp = strtotime($startdatetime);
    $endtimestamp = strtotime($enddatetime);
    $difference = abs($endtimestamp - $starttimestamp)/3600; in hours difference
```

Comment: One is a datetime and the other one is a time, and since timestamp is defined as seconds between datetime/time and 1970 00:00:00, the difference will be huge.

Comment: just extarct same date from d1 using date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2020-12-07 18:21:47')); and concatinate it with the t1 time

Comment: and then use this difference  method

Answer (score 0):

`2020-12-07 18:21:47` is not a full date time value. It is missing the time zone which can lead to unexpected or wrong results.

`strtotime()` is a very old function. The better approach is the `DateTimeImmutable` class. You can set the time with `DateTimeImmutable::setTime()` and get the difference with `DateTimeImmutable::diff()`.

```
$dates = [
    new DateTimeImmutable('2020-12-07T00:21:47Z'),
    new DateTimeImmutable('2020-12-07T00:21:47-0800'),
    new DateTimeImmutable('2020-12-07 00:21:47', new DateTimeZone('+02:00')),
    new DateTimeImmutable('2020-03-29 00:21:47', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin')),
];
$timeParts = explode(':', '19:30:00');

foreach ($dates as $date) {
    // get a modified copy of the immutable date time
    $other = $date->setTime(...$timeParts);
    var_dump($other->format(DateTimeInterface::ATOM));
    // differences as a DateInterval
    $difference = $date->diff($other);
    var_dump($difference->format('%h hour(s), %i minute(s)'));
}
```

Output:

```
string(25) "2020-12-07T19:30:00+00:00"
string(23) "19 hour(s), 8 minute(s)"
string(25) "2020-12-07T19:30:00-08:00"
string(23) "19 hour(s), 8 minute(s)"
string(25) "2020-12-07T19:30:00+02:00"
string(23) "19 hour(s), 8 minute(s)"
string(25) "2020-03-29T19:30:00+02:00"
string(23) "18 hour(s), 8 minute(s)"
```

Notice that the last result is 18 hours. This is because on March 29th is the clock change to daylight saving time in this time zone.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between two times on the same day is being sought. With this solution with [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.datetime), the date from $d1 is set to the current day, the difference is calculated and formatted.

```
$d1 = '2020-12-07 18:21:47';
$t1 = '19:30:00';

$diffHis = date_create($d1)
  ->modify(date('Y-m-d'))  
  ->diff(date_create($t1))
  ->format('%r%H:%I:%s')
;
echo $diffHis; //01:08:13
```

Another variant uses [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php) with a format that hides the date from $d1. So the time from $d1 gets the current date.

```
$diffHis = DateTime::createFromFormat('????-??-?? H:i:s',$d1)
  ->diff(date_create($t1))
 ->format('%r%H:%I:%s')
;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$d1 = '2020-12-07 18:21:47';
$t1 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2020-12-07 18:21:47')).' 19:30:00'; // or $t1 = '2020-12-07 19:30:00'; 

if( strtotime($t1) > strtotime($d1)){
    $diff = date("H:i:s",(strtotime($t1) - strtotime($d1)));
}

print_r( $diff );
```

//should return you correct result
01:08:13

Check that you are passing vars in correct way.

Comment: [It does not provide the result you claim it should.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5de17db43ba4479ca83e8156fe3da9c1f9827df7)

Comment: it will not provide accurate result

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/T5vTddRU416KkZvaibvASw

I get the result correctly, what are we missing here?

Comment: Since you didnt provide a date to your time in `$t1` it just adds the current date. Meaning: `timestamp($t1) === timestamp('2020-12-17 19:30:00')`. Thats also why `strtotime($t1) > strtotime($d1)` evaluates to `true`.